# In Quarkus to invoke request to another service with custom media type

Tags: java, rest, mime-types, quarkus

I am developing a company-interal Quarkus service. In this service, I need to call another internal service asynchronously using a customized media type.

As I am following this official document and wrote up something like this:

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.inject.RegisterRestClient;

@Path("/api")
@RegisterRestClient
public interface InternalService {

  String CUSTOM_TYPE = "application/custom";

  @GET
  @Path("/hello/{id}")
  @Produces({CUSTOM_TYPE})
  Uni<EntityClass> getHello(@PathParam("id") long id);
}
```

The `EntityClass` is actually protobuf message in my case.

In the example (https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-client), looks like one can directly inject the bean:

```
    @Inject
    @RestClient
    CountriesService countriesService;
```

I have a few questions:

1. does `resteasy` already provide an implementation for common media types?
2. How can I implement `InternalService` interface for my custom media type?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes. Please check here:

- https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/4.6.0.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#Content_Marshalling_Providers. Quarkus adds supports for some additional ones.

2. Just create your own Provider to handle the custom Media type and register it:

- https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/4.6.0.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#Content_Marshalling_with__Provider_classes
- https://download.eclipse.org/microprofile/microprofile-rest-client-2.0/microprofile-rest-client-spec-2.0.html#_provider_declaration